# Save YOLOv4 with deepSORT prediction info such as coords and ID

Tags: python, yolo

I'm following this tutorial (https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort). I now want to save the predictions into one file (csv/txt/anything) in terms of class, ID, and coordinate location. I've looked online but can't seem to find a solution. I especially need the ID value.

I can use the argument --info to show this information in the Anaconda prompt but I just need the info in a saved file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `object_tracker.py`, [line 219](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort/blob/24e675f59d556e13c680df125918ec031c4bd683/object_tracker.py#L218), and save the info to a file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("Tracker ID: {}, Class: {},  BBox Coords (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax): {}".format(str(track.track_id), class_name, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]), int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])))))
f.close
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked after I removed one of the closing parentheses!

Comment: Is there any reason why this wouldn't work in Google Colab? The rest of my script works fine but no text file is produced after adding this

Comment: Not sure. Maybe check your path and try to open you file from within the script before quitting. You can also double check [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/computationalcore/introduction-to-python/blob/master/notebooks/4-files/PY0101EN-4-2-WriteFile.ipynb)